# What's the word for an underlying theme/message in media?

Tags: single-word-requests

Like, If you want to say "this movie had liberal themes that weren't that obvious, but you can tell If you pay attention." I think the word I'm looking for starts with "sub."

Comment: Are you an Eddie Izzard fan?  He does a bit about American v. British film and uses the "sub-something" term quite well.  It's in his show "Dressed to Kill".  I found it on a fun website where you can search for specific terms used in film dialogue - subasub.com:  "Lately we've pulled out of that with Trainspotting but the smaller film, the Room With A View With A Staircase And A Pond type movie.
Films with very fine acting but the drama is rather subsued - subsumed?
A word like that. Sub-something or another. Just sort of folded in…"

Answer (score 4):

[subtext](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/subtext) 1. An implicit meaning or theme of a literary text.
2. The underlying personality of a dramatic character as implied or indicated by a script or text and interpreted by an actor in performance.

Answer (score 1):

**subliminal** might be what you're looking for...

*existing or operating below the threshold of consciousness; being or employing stimuli insufficiently intense to produce a discrete sensation but often being or designed to be intense enough to influence the mental processes or the behavior of the individual: a subliminal stimulus; subliminal advertising.

www.dictionary.com*

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be looking for is *subcurrent* (or *undercurrent*):

Definition (via Oxford Dictionaries Online):

> An underlying feeling or influence, especially one that is contrary to the prevailing atmosphere and is not expressed openly.

Example:

> The buoyant mood of his audience was certainly out of kilter with the deep undercurrent of frustration evident elsewhere in Bournemouth this week.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simple 'subtle' would suit your meaning. Any of the following senses might fill the bill, although the first seems closest:

> **subtle** *adj*
>   1. not immediately obvious or comprehensible.
>   2. difficult to detect or analyse, often through being delicate or highly refined: a subtle scent.
>   3. showing or making or capable of showing or making fine distinctions of meaning.
>   4. marked by or requiring mental acuteness or ingenuity; discriminating.

(Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014. S.v. "subtle." Retrieved April 26 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/subtle )

Answer (score 0):

[***subjacent***](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22subjacent+theme%22&oq=%22subjacent+theme%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...3331.7059.0.7489.10.10.0.0.0.0.447.1149.3-2j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..8.1.381.ls74qKj-n4U)

> : situated or occurring underneath or below; underlying.
>
> : lying at a lower level but not directly beneath.
>
> [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/subjacent)

***implicit***

> : implied though not plainly expressed.
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/fr/definition/anglais_americain/implicit)